# Sitecore Active Directory Module

Tags: active-directory, sitecore, sitecore6

Currently we have our Active Directory (LDAP) domain controller defined in the ConnectionStrings.config file. Is it possible to configure a second domain controller, as a fail-over option?

For example, recently Domain Controller 1 failed, and I had to manually change the connection string to point to Domain Controller 2 - but the website was generating errors in the mean-time (for several hours of down-time).

We are running Sitecore version 6.5
(Sitecore.NET 6.5.0 (rev. 120706) )

Comment: Hello Friend I'm new to sitecore kindly help me, how to integrate my ldap URL in to sitecore. I follow the below link "http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/modules/ad/sitecore_active_directory_module_guide_sc62-65-usletter.pdf" but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to configure a fail-over partner.

You could put a loadbalancer in between the two domain controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You could actually do that.  There are options with the AD module that allow for connecting to multiple domains and/or using multipe providers.  All pipelines in Sitecore are extendable, so there's nothing to stop you from setting this up.  You could easily do some custom coding to catch exceptions during login and switch to a different provider.  The trick is just doing the custom coding.